# How to change datasource of datawindow from procedure to query without changing source?

Tags: datasource, procedure, powerbuilder, datawindow

PowerBuilder 12.5

I do not want to edit the datawindow object source code and i want to change datasource of the datawindow where i used a stored procedure. i want to use a different stored procedure or query. How to do that without editing the source of datawindow?

Answer (score 1):

If I was in your case I would create another datawindow with the other stored procedure call, then I would change the dataobject between them with if-then-else.
If you need to have strictly the same dataobject then I would tried something with retrieval args and send as retrieval a value that would distinguish the two different options, then you can use IF-THEN-ELSE inside the datasource.

```
   IF :al_arg = 1 THEN
      call procedure1;
   ELSIF :al_arg = 2 THEN
      call procedure2;
   ELSE
      //something else    
   END IF;
```

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

I would also create a new datawindow with as data source your procedure.  Then to use it, use the `sharedata()` function.
More specifically, if you have a datawidnows control `dw_1` holding your 'old' datawindow, create a new (possibly hidden) control dw_new and use the new dataobject in it.  Alternatively, you could use a datastore.
Then code:

```
dw_1.reset // To make sure everything has been flushed
dw_new.retrieve()
dw_new.sharedata(dw_1)
```

The abolute condition for this to work is to have exactly the same buffer ie the same fields with the same definition.